# Communicating from child to parent when using Components in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-client-side

I have a blog website where comments are managed inside a `Component` called *CommentList*.

```
index.razor

...
Counting comments: @CommentCount
<CommentList PostId="@CurrentPost.Id" OnCommentCountChanged="OnCommentCountChangedHandler" />

@code {
    ...
    int CommentCount;
    public void OnCommentCountChangedHandler(int count)
    {
        CommentCount = count;
    }
}
```

And now the component:

```
CommentList.razor

[Parameter] public int PostId { get; set; }
[Parameter] public EventCallback<int> OnCommentCountChanged { get; set; }
[Inject] ICommentService CommentService { get; set; }

List<Comment> AllComments { get; set; }    
bool flag;

protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync()
{
    if (PostId && !flag)
    {
        flag = true;
        AllComments = await CommentService.GetComments(PostId);
        await CountComments();
    }
}
protected async Task CountComments()
{
    Console.WriteLine("CountComments called");
    if (AllComments == null) return;
    var count = AllComments.Count();
    await OnCommentCountChanged.InvokeAsync(count);
}
```

As you can see on the code above, in my component, I retrieved all the comments for this post though a service then I invoke a method to inform the parent of the count.

I needed to communicate the count to the parent as soon as I retrieved the list of comments. The only place I found for recomputing this count (*CountingComments*) was in `OnParametersSetAsync`.

You'll notice that I used a flag. Without this flag, there is a never ending loop:

- Calling `CountingComments` from `OnParametersSetAsync`
- Invoking `OnCommentCountChanged` from `CountingComments`
- This 'invoking' produce a call to `OnParametersSetAsync`
- Etc...

With the flag in place the loop is avoided but I wonder if this is the best approach ?

Unfortunately it is not possible to make the distinction between each parameter changes. If we have 2 or 3 parameters, if one of these parameters changed, the method `OnParametersSetAsync` is triggered but we don't have any idea which parameter is concerned. Furthermore an invoke to the `EventCallback Parameter` *OnCommentCountChanged* also trigger this `OnParametersSetAsync` with no interest (in my case).

Comment: Why disn't OnInitializedAsync not work? It's called once.

Comment: Because my service should first fetch with the Id as parameter and this parameter is retrieved in OnParameterSetAsync. I don't think Id parameter is already set in OnInitializedAsync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the OnParametersSetAsync method retrieve the comments superfluously at each execution of the method. Instead you should use OnInitalized(Async) pair of methods to retrieve the data only once, when your CommentList component is created.

Now with that design, only when a new comment is added to the current post (of the blog, mind you), you'll need to refresh the `AllComments` list by calling the CommentService.GetComments method again. How to call, when to call, etc. is all depending on your design.

Let me describe here an easy and workable design. Say at the bottom of your blog post is a comment section where you can enter a comment, and then click on a "Save my comment" button. You can define a service or Razor component to post the added comment to the relevant database table(s). This service or component should also have code to invoke an event that notify your CommentList of this occurrence (new comment added). In response, your code should call the CommentService.GetComments method to retrieve a fresh set of comments from the database.

> Unfortunately it is not possible to make the distinction between each parameter changes

Why not ?

This is how you should define your `[Parameter] public int PostId { get; set; }`

```
[Parameter] public int PostId { get; set; }

private int _internalPostId;
private int InternalPostId 
{ 
   get => _internalPostId; 
   set 
   {
     if(_internalPostId != value)
     {
        _internalPostId = value;

        // Can only be true if a new post is displayed or selected 
        // in the Index component, which requires you to retrieve the 
        // comments for the new post id passed. Put here code that 
        // call the method that perform the database access to
        // retrieve the comments. That should be the same code that 
        // you should have in OnInitalized(Async) pair of methods. So 
        // you can create a single method that should be called from 
        // OnInitalized(Async), and from here.
        // Understand that OnInitalized(Async) is called only once, 
        // when the component is created... When the PostId parameter 
        // changes, the Component is not created again, but re-used.
        // Note: If you define an asynchronous method that contain the 
        // code to retrieve the comments, you can still call it from 
        // here by applying the so-called fire-and-forget operation, 
        // as for instance:  _ = MyService.GetSomething();
     }
   } 
}
```

Note that I've introduced a new private property called `InternalPostId`. It is used because parameter properties should not be mutated by the child component... They should be treated as auto properties. Hope you're not confused.

You'll also need to override the OnParametersSet method in order to update
the internal property InternalPostId from the PostId parameter property.

```
 protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
       if (InternalPostId != PostId)
       {
           InternalPostId = PostId;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanations, it works as expected now. But I didn't understand your `Note` about the so-called fire-and-forget.

Comment: Oops... I try to put some code in the setter of InternalPostId (inside & outside the if condition). The code is never reached. Even if I change the PostId from the Index. Only the `OnParametersSet` is called. Any idea ?

Comment: Why don't you have an Event in your service - say `CommentListChanged` which get's invoked whenever you call `CommentService.GetComments(PostId)`.  Index.razor injects the service, registers an event handler with `CommentListChanged`, links the count display to a public property `CommentsCount` on the service   and then invokes `StateHasChanged`.  This gets rid of all your reverse wiring and hoop jumps.  I can post or point you at some example code if you wish.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I agree it can be done like you said but as an exercise I would like to keep the invoke in the child component. It is frequent to have more than one parameter in a component. So my problem now is (as explained in my previous comment) I moved the fetch code inside OnInitialisedAsync and I try to implement the InternalPostId as explained by enet but unfortunately it doesn't work. I mean the code in the setter is never reached.

Comment: @Bronzato, see update section in my answer. As for the first comment, I'll try to answer you question soon.

Comment: @enet Coincidence, by the time you posted your update I've finally come to the same solution as your second version :) The only remark is about `_ = await MyService.GetSomething();` I got an error "await operator can only be used within an async method". So for this moment (to avoid this error) I only call my method without the await. Thus the code is green highlighted with ~~~~~~ with the message "Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed".  But it still works. Maybe a workaround to avoid this warning ? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Bronzato.  NP :-)  The `ComponentBase` source code - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs - if you haven't already found it, provides a real insight into how components work.

Comment: "The only remark is about _ = await MyService.GetSomething();" Thousand and one apologies. You should remove the await key word. It should be _ = MyService.GetSomething(); Would you please up-vote my answer...

Comment: Great, thanks for your help ! Any doc on this affectation to underscore, this is new to me.

Comment: No, sorry... I can't provide you with a link to such docs, but I'm sure it's written and explained somewhere. I know how to use it and why to use it from observations of the .Net framework code. Incidentally, I've changed my code in my answer to work with the first version. Now that you know the second, rather easy version, learn the correct way to use parameter properties.